# How can I move a scalable external SVG files with drag and drop from one div container to another div container?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, svg, drag

I have two divcontainer. In the first divcontainer (mapcontainer) I have a map as a canvas. The second divcontainer (baucontainer) contains the external SVG-files. Now I would like to put the SVG-files with drag and drop from the second divcontainer (baucontainer) into the first divcontainer (mapcontainer). The canvas is scalable, so I must change the height and width by the dragmove. Additional the drag and drop files must be a child or a node. The SVG-files in the second divcontainer (baucontainer) are not allowed to delete.

I would like to see the SVG-Object with the new height and width when I move it and not in the original format.

Some people on the internet mean it is possible to execute this problem with d3.js.

The code is only an example, but with the original functions.

What can I do to see of SVG-file by dragmove the new height and width?

Thanks a lot !!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Stadtaufbau</title>

    <style>

      [draggable=true]
      {
        cursor      : move;  
      }

      [draggable=false]
      {
        cursor      : not-allowed;
      }

      svg
      {
        display     : block;
        width       : 100px;
        height      : auto;
      }

      #hauptcontainer
      {
        position    : relative;
        width       : 500px;
        height      : 250px;
        margin      : -8px auto auto -8px;
        z-index     : 0;
      }

      #mapcontainer
      {
        position    : absolute;
        width       : 425px;
        height      : 250px;
        float       : left;
        border      : 1px solid black;
        z-index     : 1;
        overflow    : hidden;   
      }

      #mapcanvas
      {
        width       : 425px;
        height      : 250px;
      }

      #mapcontainer mapcanvas
      {
        top         : 1px;
        left        : 1px;
        z-index     : 2;
      }

      #baucontainer
      {
        position    : absolute;
        width       : 75px;
        min-height  : 250px;
        margin-top  : 0px;
        margin-left : 426px;
        border      : 1px solid black;
        z-index     : 3;
      }

      #baumenue
      {
        position    : absolute;
        width       : 75px;
        height      : 250px;
        overflow    : auto;
        padding     : 0px;
      }

      #baumenue img
      {
        height      : 50px;
        width       : 50px;
      }

      #bauscrollbar
      {
        position    : absolute;
        height      : 248px;
      }

    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>

      var mousewheelevt = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel" //FF doesn't recognize mousewheel as of FF3.x

      var mapimg = new Image();
      mapimg.setAttribute("id", "Hauptcanvas");
      mapimg.setAttribute("src", "http://www.multidatasoft.de/map.jpg");

      var mapcanvas;
      var mapcanvasWidth;
      var mapcanvasHeight;
      var mapcontext;
      var mapoffsetX;
      var mapoffsetY;

      var windowcursorposX = 0;
      var windowcursorposY = 0;

      var Gebaeudenummer = "";

      var dragIcon = null;


      $(document).ready(function() 
      {
        mapcanvas        = document.getElementById("mapcanvas");
        mapcanvasWidth   = mapcanvas.width;
        mapcanvasHeight  = mapcanvas.height;
        mapcontext       = mapcanvas.getContext("2d");
        mapoffsetX       = $("#mapcanvas").offset().left;
        mapoffsetY       = $("#mapcanvas").offset().top;


        mapimg.onload = function(e)
        {
          mapcontext.drawImage(mapimg, 0, 0, 425, 250);
        };

      });

      function ziehen(event)
      {
        dragIcon = null;

        event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copymove';
        event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
        event.dataTransfer.setData('Text', event.target.id);

        Gebaeudenummer = event.target.id;

        dragIcon     = new Image();
        dragIcon.id  = "test";
        dragIcon.src = "http://www.multidatasoft.de/kleines_haus_" + Gebaeudenummer + ".svg";

        event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(dragIcon, 10, 10);

      }

      function ablegenErlauben(event)
      {
        event.preventDefault();
      }


      function ablegen(event)
      {
        event.preventDefault();

        windowcursorposX = (parseInt(event.clientX));
        windowcursorposY = (parseInt(event.clientY));

        mapcontext.drawImage(dragIcon, windowcursorposX, windowcursorposY, 25, 25);
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <main>
      <div id="hauptcontainer">
        <div id="mapcontainer" ondragover="ablegenErlauben(event)" ondrop="ablegen(event)">
          <canvas id="mapcanvas" class="mapcanvas">
            Entschuldigung, aber dein Browser unterstützt leider kein Canvas!
          </canvas>
        </div>
        <div id="baucontainer">
          <div id="baumenue" ondragover="ablegenErlauben(event)" ondrop="ablegen(event)">
            <img type="image/svg+xml" src="http://www.multidatasoft.de/kleines_haus_1.svg" alt="Computerbild" title="Computerbild &#10Holz: 10&#10Stein: 10&#10Gold: 10" draggable="true" ondragstart="ziehen(event)" id="1" />
            <img type="image/svg+xml" src="http://www.multidatasoft.de/kleines_haus_2.svg" alt="Computerbild" title="Computerbild &#10Holz: 10&#10Stein: 10&#10Gold: 10" draggable="true" ondragstart="ziehen(event)" id="2" />
            <img type="image/svg+xml" src="http://www.multidatasoft.de/kleines_haus_3.svg" alt="Computerbild" title="Computerbild &#10Holz: 10&#10Stein: 10&#10Gold: 10" draggable="true" ondragstart="ziehen(event)" id="3" />
            <img type="image/svg+xml" src="http://www.multidatasoft.de/kleines_haus_4.svg" alt="Computerbild" title="Computerbild &#10Holz: 10&#10Stein: 10&#10Gold: 10" draggable="true" ondragstart="ziehen(event)" id="4" />
            <img type="image/svg+xml" src="http://www.multidatasoft.de/kleines_haus_5.svg" alt="Computerbild" title="Computerbild &#10Holz: 10&#10Stein: 10&#10Gold: 10" draggable="true" ondragstart="ziehen(event)" id="5" />
            <img type="image/svg+xml" src="http://www.multidatasoft.de/kleines_haus_6.svg" alt="Computerbild" title="Computerbild &#10Holz: 10&#10Stein: 10&#10Gold: 10" draggable="true" ondragstart="ziehen(event)" id="6" />
            <img type="image/svg+xml" src="http://www.multidatasoft.de/kleines_haus_7.svg" alt="Computerbild" title="Computerbild &#10Holz: 10&#10Stein: 10&#10Gold: 10" draggable="true" ondragstart="ziehen(event)" id="7" />
            <img type="image/svg+xml" src="http://www.multidatasoft.de/kleines_haus_8.svg" alt="Computerbild" title="Computerbild &#10Holz: 10&#10Stein: 10&#10Gold: 10" draggable="true" ondragstart="ziehen(event)" id="8" />
            <img type="image/svg+xml" src="http://www.multidatasoft.de/kleines_haus_9.svg" alt="Computerbild" title="Computerbild &#10Holz: 10&#10Stein: 10&#10Gold: 10" draggable="true" ondragstart="ziehen(event)" id="9" />
            <img type="image/svg+xml" src="http://www.multidatasoft.de/kleines_haus_10.svg" alt="Computerbild" title="Computerbild &#10Holz: 10&#10Stein: 10&#10Gold: 10" draggable="true" ondragstart="ziehen(event)" id="10" />
          </div>
          <div id="bauscrollbar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```